Word Add-In in React. Track Changes not working as expected
I am trying to let an algorithm automatically Track Changes in a Word Document. In this Case I want it to correct a string to in Track Changes Mode. However, the Track Changes Mode is not working as expected. In Word, a User would accept or decline the Change and either the original or the correction would stay. With my implementation though, the User has to accept and decline both the correction and the original. Also, a string which already has a correction recommendation gets that recommendation again so that there are two corrections. The manual Track Changes mode shows very different behaviour.
I want a Bot to be able to automatically correct passages of a certain text. But I want suggestions of the bot to be in Track Changes Mode.
This is my Code. Thanks for your help!
export async function correctSpellingMistakes() {
  const searchWord = "§ 210";
  const suggestion = "§ 211";

  try {
    await Word.run(async (context) => {
      const body = context.document.body;
      const searchResults = body.search(searchWord, { matchCase: false, matchWholeWord: true });

      context.load(searchResults, 'items');

      await context.sync();

      await setChangeTrackingMode("trackAll");

      if (searchResults.items.length > 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < searchResults.items.length; i++) {
          const match = searchResults.items[i];

          match.font.strikeThrough = true;

          match.insertText(`${suggestion}`, 'After');
        }

        await context.sync();
      }

      await setChangeTrackingMode("off");

      await context.sync();
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error:', error);
  }
}


Result:
§ 210§ 211§ 211 (Last both underlined) des Strafgesetzbuches (StGB) in Deutschland definiert den Mord als vorsätzliche Tötung eines Menschen, die durch besonders verwerfliche Merkmale gekennzeichnet ist. Diese Merkmale werden in drei Kategorien unterteilt: Die erste Kategorie betrifft die Beweggründe der Tat, wie Mordlust, Befriedigung des Geschlechtstriebs, Habgier oder sonstige niedrige Beweggründe. Die zweite Kategorie umfasst die Art und Weise der Tatausführung, wie Heimtücke, Grausamkeit oder die Verwendung gemeingefährlicher Mittel. Die dritte Kategorie bezieht sich auf die Zielsetzungen des Täters, wie die Ermöglichung oder das Verdecken einer anderen Straftat. Ein Mord gemäß § 210§ 211§ 211 (Last both underlined) StGB wird mit lebenslanger Freiheitsstrafe bestraft, was die besondere Schwere dieses Verbrechens und die hohe gesellschaftliche Verurteilung zum Ausdruck bringt.

You are missing some code to show what Word is. Please provide more context and how this piece of code is used.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Word represents the applications object. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/word/word.application?view=word-js-preview
